# Function for label variable before plotting in R

Tags: r, function, label

I hope, this question is not too easy for this forum (actually, I'm almost a bit embarrassed to ask this question here, but I'm struggeling with this small issue the whole day...)

I have dataframes look like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(runif(4),
             c("po", "pr", "po", "pr"),
             c("Control 1","Control 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1"))

names(df) <- list("values", "test_type", "group")
```

Now, I want easliy re-label the variables "test_type" and "group" for the plot afterwards. (it's nicer to read "pretest" instead of "pr" in a presentation :-) )
I could do it manually with:

```
df$test_type <- factor(df$test_type,
                     levels = c("pr", "po"),
                     labels = c("pretest", "posttest"))
df$group <- factor(df$group,
                 levels = c("Control 1", "Treatment 1"),
                 labels = c("control", "EST"))
```

In this case, I would have to repeat this for a lot more dataframes, which lead me to write a function:

```
var_label <- function(df, test, groups){

# Create labels
df$test_type <- factor(df$test,
                     levels = c("pr", "po"),
                     labels = c("pretest", "posttest"))
df$group <- factor(df$groups,
                 levels = c("Control 1", "Treatment 1"),
                 labels = c("control", "EST"))

return(list(df$test_type, df$group))
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I tried a lot slight different versions and also different command from the Hmisc package, but none of these worked. I know, I can solve this problem in another way, but I try to write more efficient and shorter codes and would be really interested, what I have to change to make this function work. Or even better do you have a suggestion for a more efficient way?

Thank you a lot in advance!!

Comment: You need to read `help("$")`.

Comment: Have you looked at `?forcats::fct_relabel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned above, I think `forcats::fct_relabel()` is what you want here, along with `dplyr::mutate_at()`. Assuming that your relabeling needs are no more complex than what has been outlined in your question, the following should get you what you appear to be looking for.

```
####BEGIN YOUR DATAFRAME CREATION####
df <- data.frame(runif(4),
                 c("po", "pr", "po", "pr"),
                 c("Control 1","Control 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1"))

names(df) <- list("values", "test_type", "group")
#####END YOUR DATAFRAME CREATION#####

# Load dplyr and forcats
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

# create a map of labels and levels based on your implied logic
# the setup is label = level
label_map <- c("pretest" = "pr"
               ,"posttest" = "po"
               ,"control" = "Control 1" 
               ,"EST" = "Treatment 1")

# create a function to exploit the label map
fct_label_select <- function(x, map) {
  names(which(map == x))
}

# create a function which is responsive to a character vector
# as required by fct_relabel
fct_relabeler <- function(x, map) {
  unlist(lapply(x, fct_label_select, map = map))
}

fct_relabeler(levels(df$test_type), map = label_map)

# function to meet your apparent needs
var_label <- function(df, cols, map){
  df %>%
    mutate_at(.vars = cols
              ,.fun = fct_relabeler
              ,map = map)
}

var_label(df = df, cols = c("test_type", "group"), map = label_map)

# values test_type   group
# 1 0.05159681  posttest control
# 2 0.89050323   pretest control
# 3 0.42988881  posttest     EST
# 4 0.32012811   pretest     EST
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This is what I looked for! I haven't known the forcats package yet, but this works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately,  after some time not using this code from above, I had the following error message today:
`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: argument ".fun" is missing, with no default.`

As this code worked totally fine over a lot of different graphs, I am really helpless in debugging this error! 
Does anybody know by chance about some important updates of "dplyr" that could entail this error?

Comment: I'm not at a computer to check, but have you tried just dropping the `s` from the `.funs` param? i.e. change it to `.fun`?

Comment: yes, does not work. Also to set a `.` before `,fun` does not change the error message. 
I restarted R, I tried to look at dplyr::mutate_at function, but I can't find a solution (at least to the best of MY knowledge, which is very limited in programming...)

Comment: I found the solution and edited the code above. Now, it works again.